# Best way to display an editable List of Strings?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, user-interface

I want to display a List of Strings to my customers - but the catch is: The list has to be editable, e. G. new Items have to be added, existing ones to be deleted or edited.
I browsed a while and found nothign really nice to achieve this: A ListView is cumbersome to program and a Datagrid seems to be better - but has an annoying problem: If you add rows, this is not reflected in the base List.
How do you solve this problem?

Existing code:

```
 public sealed class ExcelExcludeWordsList
  {
     public ObservableCollection<ExcelExcludedWord> ExcludedStrings 
  }

    public class ExcelExcludedWord
    {
        public string Word { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a DataGrid? Try to make your objects Observable and bind to your list.

Comment: I have tried that, but adding rows is a problem. The user can do it at will, but the changes are not reflected in the Collection.

Comment: Try using an [`ObservableCollection(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx).

Comment: I think the problem is not with the controls, but with your data model. Read more about the MVVM pattern principles and techniques for WPF and you will succeed. A good start is to have a ViewModel base class and implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface; Also frameworks like the `MVVM Light Toolkit` might help.

Comment: @thomasjaworski.com: This is a MVVM application - just not one of the core screens but a quick solution. This it is very easy to build such a "view" in ASP:net, I was wondering if there is a WPF solution for this.

Comment: I would use some sort of ItemsControl bound to an Observable Collection.  This way you can just create an event or command in code behind that will add a new element to the observable collection and your UI will update.

Comment: You should post a screen shot of a sketch of what you want.  You will get better answers.

Comment: yes, also what @SteelNation says it really depends; Sometimes even a Text area will do, where you just ask the user to enter any items and separate them by comma or new lines, and you just split the list on save.

Comment: Binding your ObservableCollection<ExcelExcludedWord> to a DataGrid should do what you're after. Could you post some more code: The rest of the ExcelExcludeWordsList class, your DataGrid xaml code, and how you bind the collection to the grid?

Comment: @Sphinxxx Thank you, I followed your Idea and developed an acceptable solution. 
Might you post this as answer=

Comment: Nah, @Romoku said it first, so that would be stealing his thunder :)